# Two Maven Dependencies with different scope

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

If I have the following two dependencies in the same `pom.xml` file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And I'd like to remove the redundancy. So should I delete the one with scope as `runtime` because it's included in the other dependency?

Also I'd be happy to understand why one would specify a dependency with scope of `runtime`.

Answer (score 2):

From [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism - Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> - `compile`
>
>   - This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
>
> (...)
>
> - `runtime`
>
>   - This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

So if you have a `compile` dependency, `runtime` is already included and therefore superfluous.

As an example for when to use `runtime`, take the [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) logging API: you compile your sources against `slf4j-api.jar` (`compile` dependency), but not the actual implementation, which is distributed separately (and there are several to choose from). However, when packaging your application or running unit tests, Maven should still include an implementation jar, e.g. `slf4j-simple.jar` (`runtime` dependency), because otherwise nothing will be logged.